# Default config settings for a new git repository?

Tags: git, configuration

When I create a new git repository, some configurations settings are automatically added to **.git/config**. Where can I change these default settings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering the option template of [`git init`](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html):

```
 --template=<template_directory>
```

> Provide the directory from which templates will be used. The default template directory is `/usr/share/git-core/templates`.
>
> When specified, `<template_directory>` is used as the source of the template files rather than the default.
>   The template files include some directory structure, some suggested "exclude patterns", and copies of non-executing "hook" files. The suggested patterns and hook files are all modifiable and extensible.

If you look at the git sources for [creating a new db](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/init-db.c), you could include a config file with your default value there.

The [function  `create_default_files()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/565301e41670825ceedf75220f2918ae76831240/builtin/init-db.c#L180) does have:

```
 /* First copy the templates -- we might have the default
  * config file there, in which case we would want to read
  * from it after installing.
  */
copy_templates(template_path);
```

The [git/config.c](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/config.c) has the `git_default_core_config()` function which set default values.

Comment: @Jubobs I have restored the link.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that the settings are determined automatically and cannot be changed. E.g. I want to change the default setting for core.filemode, but this is hardcoded based on a check ("`/* Check filemode trustabililty */`").

Comment: I added a file `/usr/share/git-core/templates/config`, with `filemode = false` and a random `xyz = foo` in the `[core]` section. The `xyz = foo` works, but the `filemode = false` is overwritten thanks to the hardcoded logic mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

All git global configs can be altered by the `--global` supplied at the command line.

For eg:

```
git config --global user.name "First Last"
git config --global user.email "email@somewhere.com"
```

Update:

All existing git configs can be found by

```
git config -l
```

Also, `git config -e` opens an editor for editing.

Comment: The question was about default values that are written to _local_ config in every newly-created repository. This has nothing to do with global settings, because local config overrides global one.