# What are some of your favorite settings in Git configuration files to make Git Fun?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration

What are your favorite Git configuration settings which make your life easy while working with Git?

Comment: Any more tips & tricks with Git Configuraton ?

Comment: @Sure: in the meantime, you can also define your own config default setting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093077/default-config-settings-for-a-new-git-repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aliases I mention in [Trimming GIT Checkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins/2302947#2302947) (and the `fixup!` action from the recent Git1.7.0):

```
[alias]
    fixup = !sh -c 'git commit -m \"fixup! $(git log -1 --format='\\''%s'\\'' $@)\"' -
    squash = !sh -c 'git commit -m \"squash! $(git log -1 --format='\\''%s'\\'' $@)\"'
```

, really help me to commit very often even though I am in the middle of *one* task, allowing me to finish it with one coherent commit at the end (instead of too many small intermediate commits).
Not exactly "fun", but very useful.

Comment: Depending on how you're using this, you can probably get the same effect with `git commit (--fixup|--squash) $commit`

Answer (score 5):

Best one I have was picked up off [Scott Chacon](http://progit.org/about.html) from a talk he gave:

```
[alias]
    lol = log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate
```

I get excited every time I type `git lol`.

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

It makes diffs and things pretty. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
alias gs='git status'
alias ga='git add .'
alias gc='git commit -m'
```

This is 80% of the typing I do in git on any given day. I know I can combine the last two aliases with the `-am` flag, but it's nice to have the separated, that way I can check the status of the index before I commit.