# git: global configs not getting used in repositories

Tags: git

I have set a couple global configs in git:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.filemode false
```

These show up in my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    editor = vim
    autocrlf = true
    fileMode = false
```

however, my repositories continue to check filemodes and continue to commit Windows line endings.  I have to execute the `git config` command within each repository or the configs don't get loaded.

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have overrides in your local git repo config file?

If you `cd` to your repository and run:

```
$ cat .git/config
```

Are there any settings in there with the same keys but different globals to your global presets?

**Edit:**

I slightly misunderstood the way git works. It will look in the local config file and if it doesn't exist, fall back to the global one.

Based on the conversation below, it appears having `fileMode` set to `true` is [baked into the Git core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093077/default-config-settings-for-a-new-git-repository#comment65325465_2093395).

I would suggest making an alias (or two):

```
[alias]
    create = init && git config core.fileMode false
```

Comment: ok, that's why. Thanks.  but it leads me to another question.  the `.git` folder is ignored by `.gitignore`, so it isn't getting those configs from the repo.  why are they defaulting to the values I don't want when I clone the repo, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Hmm odd, when you initialise a new repo or clone, it should take the settings from your global file and put them in the local file. Does it even do it if you do a fresh clone of a repo? What about if you run `git init` then view that config file?

Comment: when I execute `git init` I get a config file that has `filemode` set to `true` and no value for `autocrlf`. Now that I look again, none of the repos have `autocrlf` set, but I also notice that the line endings arent actually getting committed, so that one isn't a problem.  `filemode` is still strange though

Comment: I've misunderstood git and your question. I've done some digging and the `gitconfig` is only used if local settings don't exist (in the example of your `autocrlf`). However, I'm looking into how you change the global setting

Comment: So we can forget about `autocrlf`. I was misinterpreting the behavior. What I'm confused about is why `filemode` is being initialized to true when the global setting is false.

Comment: Looks like it's hard coded and you'll have to do it on a per repo basis - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093077/default-config-settings-for-a-new-git-repository#comment65325465_2093395 - I have updated my answer above